# cakephp: access a variable in same controller but different function

Tags: php, cakephp, global-variables, cakephp-2.0

i wish to access a variable in cakephp which is global in scope - that is it is in same controller but different function. 
code:

homeController.php

```
    public function opauth_complete() {
    //global $facebook_data;
    $this->facebook_data = $this->data;
     debug($this->facebook_data); // returns data
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'home', 
                          'action' => 'user_home'));
}
public function user_home()
{
   // i wish to use $facebook_data here.
debug($this->facebook_data); // returns null

}
```

how do i implement this without using session?

Answer (score 2):

you can store it in session

```
class HomeController extends Controller {        

    public function opauth_complete() {
      //assign the value
      $this->Session->write("facebook_data", $this->data);
     debug($this->facebook_data); // returns data
      $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'home', 
                          'action' => 'user_home'));
    }
    public function user_home() {
       //read from session
    debug($this->Session->read("facebook_data")); // returns data
    }
...
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without session?

Comment: @z22 well, i dont think so, because you are redirecting to other function, data in your local variable ($this->facebook_data) will not be available after redirect.

Comment: actually i tried it with session also but it still returns null, do i need to define the session helper?

Comment: yes you need to include Session Component in your Controller, if not already added in AppController, like using var $components = array('Session');

Comment: well i did so, but still it returns null :(, where am i getting wrong?

Comment: Does session variable 'facebook_data' contain anything inside opauth_complete()? Read that session opauth_complete().

Answer (score 2):

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {

   private $FbData = array();

   public function opauth_complete() {
      $this->FbData = $this->data;
   }

   public function user_home(){
      debug($this->FbData); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable in beforeFilter(), and You can use everywhere in controller

Comment: That would expire... wouldn't it?